# How do I associate my subgroup with group during migration with Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, migration, drupal-8

The wonderful https://www.drupal.org/project/group module has finally got the stable status. A patch for subgroups was developed for this module, but it was replaced by a new module from the maintainer. The subgroup module can be found here: https://www.drupal.org/project/subgroup

my problem is the following: i have written a sql-migration from another system. the database is based on the group RC5 module + subgroup patch. there everything went through correctly and worked very well. but the migration with the new subgroup module doesn't work anymore, because the basis of the module has changed a lot.

primarily my problem is the following, i migrate my parent group (group), then the child group (subgroup). but i can't get it to associate the child group to the parent group.

i asked the maintainer (https://www.drupal.org/project/subgroup/issues/3159439) what i would have to do to make my migration work with the new subgroup module. they recommended that i should write a process plugin, unfortunately i have never done this before and don't know where to start. could someone help me with this?

my structure looks like this:

```
group user role: manager, editor
two groups: parent (group), child (subgroup).

subgroup tree is configured:
parent group
parent group -> child group

subgroup tree user:
parent group manager -> child group manager
parent group editor -> child group editor

manager has rights at parent group for add group entities for chieldgroup (subgroup)
```

would be nice if someone could give me an example or tell me what to consider. i think that this module is used very often, this question is often asked. great would be of course a generic plugin that you could use directly.